# Selenium: Help to verify that elements are sorted by price

Tags: java, selenium, selenide

Basically, I understand how it works but I can't get it together. 
So I have `cssSelector` for all sorted elements.

I know the exact amount of those elements (12). I use `findElements()` to find them all, it returns List. But `List` of what? - `int`, `String` ?

`Selector` leads right to a price in numbers but won't understand how and where should I use that List ?
 How can I put it in the cycle to check that elements are sorted?

I use `Selenide` but if you provide me with **tips\guides** how to do that in `Selenium` it will be OK.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to verify that the found price `list` are in `sorted` order or not use as below :-

[Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) provides this functionality to verify `sorting` by it's `Ordering` class :-

Assuming you already have a price `list` from page that contains `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` values, you could verify it by using [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) library that this list is `sorted` or not in just one line as below :-

```
boolean isSorted = Ordering.natural().isOrdered(list);
System.out.println(isSorted);
```

Or

You could also make your own `generic` method to verify as below :-

```
private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> boolean isSorted(List<T> list){
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size()-1; i++) {
        if(list.get(i).compareTo(list.get(i+1))> 0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


boolean isSorted = isSorted(list);
System.out.println(isSorted);
```

**Note** :- if it prints `true` means your `list` is in `sorted` order otherwise `not`

Hope it will help you...:)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I guess this is it :)  But few more questions left -   Should I use it in the same method where I create that `list`? Looking back at @RemcoW comment, what should I put in the `isOrdered()` part? `values` or `elements`?  Thanks again

Comment: @Viterzgir you just put `values` in `isOrdered()` as like `isOrdered(values);`...

Comment: @Viterzgir by the help of RemcoW answer you could  built the list of price and after that you can pass this list as like `Ordering.natural().isOrdered(values)` or `isSorted(values)` to verify it is sorted or not..

Answer (score 1):

(This is in Selenium)

`findElements()` will provide you with a list of `WebElements`. You can take actions on each of these.

Since you want to sort them I am assuming the elements you are getting have some sort of text in them. Let's say we have this `HTML`.

```
<span>3</span>
<span>7</span>
<span>6</span>
<span>4</span>
<span>8</span>
```

`findElements()` can return all these spans. So I will get a `List` containing 5 `WebElements`. I can get the text of these `WebElements` with `getText()`. Example:

```java
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector('span'));
    for (WebElement element : elements) {
        values.add(Integer.parseInt(element.getText());
    }
```

Now you'll have a list with values. I'll leave the sorting up to you as there is so many ways you could do this.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply :) But I already have all elements sorted on the page, elements contain different numbers (I don't have to ). So I should check if filtering works well.

Comment: P.S. So your code will create an Array that consist of 5 span elements, right?

Comment: @Viterzgir The elements `List` will be an `Array` containing the 5 `span` elements. The values `List` will be an `Array` containing the text of these spans converted to an `int`. So `[3, 7, 6, 4, 8]`.

Comment: Also, here's another question: how can I use this stuff in cycle? So I have another method with cycle:    `int i;  
        for (i = 0; i < values.length -1; i++); {  
            if (values[i] < values[i + 1]) {  
                return true;  
            }  
            else {  
                return false;  
            }  
        }`  is it correct compare to your part of code? Sorry, feeling really dumb with all this :(

Comment: @Viterzgir I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve with the values. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: I took that `values` from your part of code :) I thought that the best way of verifying sorting order is to run array through the cycle. That's it

Comment: thanks for help. You helped a lot. Your and Saurabh Gaur help is legendary :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean VerifyingSort() {
    List<WebElement> theList=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"qv-drop\"]/li"));
    int FisrtfinalPrice=0;
        String FirstPrice=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"qv-drop\"]/li[1]/div[1]/div[2]/a/div[2]/div[1]")).getText();
        FirstPrice=FirstPrice.replaceAll("[\\-\\?\\+\\.\\^:,\\\u20B9]","");
        FirstPrice = FirstPrice.split(" ")[1];
        FisrtfinalPrice=Integer.parseInt(FirstPrice);
    for(int SortCheckNumber=2;SortCheckNumber<theList.size()-1;SortCheckNumber++) {
        String nextPrice=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"qv-drop\"]/li["+SortCheckNumber+"]/div[1]/div[2]/a/div[2]/div[1]")).getText();
        nextPrice=nextPrice.replaceAll("[\\-\\?\\+\\.\\^:,\\\u20B9]","");
        nextPrice = nextPrice.split(" ")[1];
        int finalNextPrice=Integer.parseInt(nextPrice);
        if(finalNextPrice>FisrtfinalPrice) {
            System.out.println("notSorted");
            return false;
        }else {
            FisrtfinalPrice=finalNextPrice;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("allSorted");
    return true;
}
```